# Motivational example for introducing singular distributions fom Rosenthal

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, lebesgue-measure

I am studying Rosenthal´s book, and I am stuck on one example, where author is showing why it is neccesary to consider distributions diffrent from absolutely continuous or discrete.

Well, what I don´t understand is the fact, that $P(Y \in S)=1$ (by law of large numbers, I dont see how the average of partial sums converges to 2/3) and also why the measure of introduced set is $\lambda = 0.$

Here is the screen of the motivational example.

[image: a]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Since the $Z_n$ are i.i.d, by the strong-law of large numbers
$$
\frac{d_1(Y)+\dotsb d_n(Y)}{n}=\frac{Z_1+\dotsb+Z_n}{n}\to EZ_1=P(Z_1=1)=\frac{2}{3}
$$
almost surely as $n\to \infty$. Hence $P(Y\in S)=1.$

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't notice, that $d_{i}(Y)$ is actually $Z_{i}.$ But, I would have second question: why is the mesure of $S$ equal to $0.$ What´s the reason, that it contains only countably many numbers?

Comment: No, it's uncountable.  But almost all members of $[0,1]$ have that limit $= 1/2$ rather than $2/3$, again by the strong law of large numbers.